# How to print nullity correlation matrix

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I've a trainingset which has 400 features and most of them have null value.

I tried to draw the heatmap of nullity correlation matrix by means of Python and [`missingno`](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno), but the heatmap is unreadable due to high number of features.

How can I print the nullity correlation matrix, instead of draw it?

Comment: Hi, and welcome! What framework are you currently using? If it can draw the heatmap, surely you can retrieve the values somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas`, the nullity correlation matrix seems to be obtained by `df.isnull().corr()` (this is how it is done is `missingno`), and this makes sense.

`missingno` package also states, in the `heatmap` function documentation, that for large datasets the `dendogram` view is better. However, it does not tell me if "large" means many features or entries.